# Combine lists from two lists of list into a single list of lists

Tags: python

```py
def combine_in_place(first, second):
    combined = []
    maxLength = max(len(first), len(second))
    for i in range(maxLength):
        if len(first) < i+1:
            combined.append(second[i])
        elif len(second) < i+1:
            combined.append(first[i])
        else:
            if not first[i]:
                combined.append(second[i])
            elif not second[i]:
                combined.append(first[i])
            else:
                combined.append(first[i] + second[i])

    return combined


print combine_in_place([['f'], ['j', 't'], [], ['s'], [], []], [['h', 'd'], [], [], []])
    # prints: [['f', 'h', 'd'], ['d', 't'], [], ['s'], [], []]
```

So I know to program (been programming in Java for some time now). I am trying to learn Python but I am not sure what's the best way to do some stuff. My question is:
How to write the function in a more *Pythonic* way?

Comment: The title should describe what the code does. Please [edit] it. Maybe you missed the placeholder on the title element: "_State the task that your code accomplishes. Make your title distinctive._". Also from  [How to Ask](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._".

Comment: (Sorry for jumping in and coercing the title during suggested edit review.)

Comment: `I know to program` & `combine_in_place([['f'], ['j', 't'], …], [['h', 'd'], …])`& `# prints: [['f', 'h', 'd'], ['d', 't'], …]` hm, hm, hm, hm.

Comment: What does `in_place` mean in the name? Surely our definition differ as you are returning a _new_ list.

Comment: I'm fairly shocked that no-one's dropped the 1 line `itertools` way. It's just `return map(chain.from_iterable, zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=()))`.

Comment: @Peilonrayz Depending on what you expect as a result, [that's close enough](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/235188/combine-lists-from-two-lists-of-list-into-a-single-list-of-lists#comment460265_235194)

Comment: Can you describe the algorithm for combining them? It seems slightly odd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would write something like that:

```
def combine(first, second):
    ret_list = []
    for i, j in zip(first, second):
        add = []
        if i is not None:
            add.extend(i)
        if j is not None:
            add.extend(j)
        ret_list.append(add)
    return ret_list
```

I don't know if it is the most python-ish way but it is ok I think...

I mean you can also write something like this:

```
def combine(first, second):
    return [(i.extend(j) if not (i is None or j is None) else i if j is None else j) for i, j in zip(first, second)]
```

But you cannot read and debug that. So I would strongly recommend against it.

Btw: Did not test the last one so I hope I did not forget a closing bracket ;)

**Edit:**

In order to keep all elements you have to add something to the end. The zip() function stops iterating after the shortest element reached its end.
This is why the following method is needed instead of zip:

```
def combine(first, second):
    ret_list = []
    for i, j in itertools.zip_longest(first, second):
        add = []
        if i is not None:
            add.extend(i)
        if j is not None:
            add.extend(j)
        ret_list.append(add)
    return ret_list
```

Note: Itertools simply must be imported first. (For Python2 it is `itertools.izip_longest()`...)

Comment: This works but I want to keep empty lists at the end as well (which I did not make clear in my question). I edited my question to include that request.

Comment: When I tested the combine function, it removed the empty ones at the end.

Comment: @ShehabEllithy yeah forgot something. Wait a sec.

Comment: Perfect, that is what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I might do it:

```
from itertools import chain
from typing import List

def combine_in_place(*lists: List[List[str]]) -> List[List[str]]:
    return [
        list(chain(*[a[i] if i < len(a) else [] for a in lists])) 
        for i in range(max(len(a) for a in lists))
    ]
```

Some general principles I've attempted to follow:

1. When you're operating on multiple things, try to express them as a single iterable rather than individual named variables
2. If you can replace a bunch of individual `if x < y` with a single call to `min()` or `max()`, do that
3. It's generally preferable to build a list through comprehension rather than using `extend`/`append`.

Comment: Since you reached for `itertools`, I’d use [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) with a `fillvalue` of `[]` or `()`. Then you can have the simpler `[list(chain.from_iterable(elements)) for elements in zip_longest(*lists, fillvalue=[])]`

Answer (score 2):

The Pythonic way may include:
 • *know and follow your [Python Enhancement Proposals](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/#introduction)* and
 • *know and exploit your [Python Standard Library](https://docs.python.org/library/#the-python-standard-library)*;
 • *follow sound development practices* is debatably language oblivious

The code presented does not violate *PEP 8* [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds)
It does not follow *PEP 257* [Docstring Conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#what-is-a-docstring)
or *PEP 484* [Type Hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#abstract)

Documenting code, in Python using docstrings, is one of my pet programming peeves:
Note how implementations in answers follow the one in the question in *not* combining *in place*, neither in the inner lists, nor in the outer one.
Note also how `_in_place` got omitted in [Cedced_Bro's accepted answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/235190/93149).
No (previous) answer has suggested using/returning a [generator](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generators) or allowing [an arbitrary number of lists](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists), given the advantages, this, too, may be due to lacking documentation of `combine_in_place()`.